# break/delay inside javascript for loops to run css animation one after another

Tags: javascript, arrays, for-loop, svg, css-animations

to ask for a solution to our problem, we’re briefly going to explain our current situation: we would like to „flash on“ various countries in a world map (svg file). Our function receives an array with the ID’s given for the countries while our for-loop should be able to call these up (shown as a CSS animation). 
According to the console the array does pass through correctly (with the loop) and also the animation is working.

Our problem however is that the animation is executing all countries at the same time instead of doing that one after another. We’ve already tried break, delay, setTimeout, setIntervall inside and outside of the for loop. Unfortunately, nothing worked.

Is there anybody who can help us?

Thanks.

```js
var htData = [
    ["DE", "00:00"],
    ["CO", "01:00"],
    ["US-3", "02:00"],
    ["IT", "03:00"]
];

function animateColor() {
  var j = -1;
  while(j < 3){
  j = getIds(j);
  console.log("animateColor: "+j);
  }
}

function getIds(elem) {
  for (var i = elem+1; i < htData.length; i++) {
    var htNow = htData[i][0];
    console.log("Daten For-Schleife: "+ htNow);
    $('#'+htNow).css({
        animation: "mymove 5s infinite"
      });
    return i;
  }
}
```

Comment: "Nothing worked" is not a sufficient description of your problem.

Comment: Sorry for this incorrect description. We mean that these functions did not solve our problem. (CSS animation runs for all countries at the same time, but we want it to run one after another)

Answer (score 0):

You  need to set an `animation-delay` for each element. In shorthand form, it is the second time value listed.

`"01:00"` is neither a valid nor a helpfull time format in CSS context. You need either a `s` or `ms` unit identifier. But let's leave it in in case you want to state both minutes and seconds.

`infinite` means the animation is repeated forever. That does not fit your requirement to run it "one after the other". I understand you want to run the animation once for each element?

```
var htData = [
    ["DE", "00:00"],
    ["CO", "01:00"],
    ["US-3", "02:00"],
    ["IT", "03:00"]
];

function parse (str) {
    return parseInt(str, 10);
}

function setAnimation (datum) {
    var parts = datum[1].split(':').map(parse);
    var time = parts[0] * 60 + parts[1];
    $('#'+ datum[0]).css({
        animation: "mymove 5s " + time + "s"
    });
    // On every browser that understands CSS animations
    // you can avoid the use of jQuery with
    // document.querySelector('#'+ datum[0]).style.animation = "mymove 5s " + time + "s";
}

htData.forEach(setAnimation);
```